# stop running a shiny app keyboard shortcut

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am running an application from R Studio.  What is the keyboard shortcut in Linux to stop running a shiny application. For example, the shortcut to start the application is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.  I looked but did not find the short-cut to stop the application.  There is a red stop sign icon to stop it using the mouse.

There must be a keyboard shortcut somewhere.

Here is my YAML

```
---
title: "HR Analytics"
runtime: shiny
output: html_notebook
---
```

Comment: does pressing `esc` do the trick?

Comment: The stop sign is still red.  Actually I am in html_notebook.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create an event for it yourself. This stops the app when the user presses `ESC` (27).

```
library(shiny)
runApp( list(ui = bootstrapPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("results"),
  tags$script('
              $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
              Shiny.onInputChange("keypressed", e.which);
              });
              '),
  p('This is a demo app')
  )
  , server = function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$keypressed,
             {
               if(input$keypressed==27)
                 stopApp()
             })
  }
))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that's useful. But I think the OP meant a shortcut from within shiny. I too would like this - I have to hunt and click the red dot hundreds of times a day when developing and debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but here goes.

If you want to stop the running Shiny application from the RStudio IDE without having to remove your hand from the keyboard, you can simply hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. No need to include `observeEvent` or the like.

Note: I haven't tested this on Linux. It works for me on Windows 10 with RStudio Version 1.1.456.